# Convolution of two $L^1$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Let $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}).$ Define the convolution $f*g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$  by $(f*g)(x)=\int\limits_{y\in \mathbb{R}}f(x-y)g(y)dy.$

Note that Fubini's theorem and translation invariance of Lebesgue measure implies that
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{R}\int\limits_{R} |f(x-y)g(y)|dydx = ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}||g||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now, again invoking Fubini's theorem we get,
$(f*g)(x)=\int\limits_{y\in \mathbb{R}}f(x-y)g(y)dy < \infty$ for a.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Furthermore, $f*g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$

**Question: Do we have $|(f*g)(x)|< \infty $ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}?$ If yes, how to prove it, if not, what are the  counter examples?**

Comment: I think it is false. It would be true if one of the function was bounded.

Comment: For example $1/|x|^a$ is locally integrable if $a<1$ but $1/|x|^a * 1/|x|^b = C/|x|^{a+b-1}$ so if $b<1$ but $a+b >1$, the function is unbounded. I believe the same works by replacing the two functions by $L^1$ functions with the same behaviour at $x=0$

Comment: You can take for example $a=b=3/4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined as
\begin{align}
f(x)=g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}&\text{if $0<|x|<1$}\\
0&\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, $f,g\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$, so $f*g$ is well-defined a.e. However, the convolution at the origin is
\begin{align}
(f*g)(0)&:=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(0-y)g(y)\,dy\\
&=\int_{0<|y|<1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|-y|}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|y|}}\,dy\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{1}{y}\,dy\\
&=\infty.
\end{align}
So, no the convolution need not be finite at every point. (The idea behind this is that the pointwise product of $L^1$ functions need not be $L^1$ again).